# Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?, ...] Error in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am making an IONIC project, and i get that error when I add Geolocation to my providers. If I take it out of the providers then my app works and even my proffessor can't solve it.
This is my file:
app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Geolocation } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [Geolocation, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy 
}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have these 2 plugins in my dependencies:

```
   "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.4.0",
   "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^6.4.0",
```

And it's driving me crazy,

I have tried to delete them, restar te project, delete and restart my node_modules folders but nothing works. I have another project using the same plugin, on my computer and it works, so the problem is with this project,

Any help is welcomed, thanks

Comment: You should take Geolocation out of the `providers` array. That's not supposed to be there.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu  I am also having the same issue. Can you please provide an example of what the app.module.ts file should look like if we are using awesome-cordova-plugins? Thanks

Comment: I tried to take it out of providers but that way I cannot use it on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied and pasted the folder, and it createt a new one "folder's name - copy" and it just worked.

It was, most lilely, a problem on how the libraries got installed
I hope that helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).